# Difficulty in placing 2 div side by side in html page

Tags: html, css

I am trying to place two div side be side but I am not able to. I have done google and previous stackoverflow search about same problem and tried to use those but it didn't work for me.
Here is my source:

**HTML:**

```html
<section id="controls" class="body">

<div id="TM" class="body">     
<img src="images/maps.PNG" height="100%" width="100%" alt="location" class="photo" /> 
</div>  

<div id="wrapper" class="body">
<div id="BL" class="body"></div>  
<div id="BR" class="body"></div>  
</div>  

</section><!-- /#controls -->


<section id="extras" class="body">
  <div class="blogroll">

  </div><!-- /.blogroll -->

  <div class="social">

  </div><!-- /.social -->
</section><!-- /#controls -->
```

**CSS:**

```css
#controls { height: 600px; width: 800px }
#wrapper { width: 800px;  height: 300px }
#TM { width:100%; border:1px solid black; height: 300px }
#BL { width:50%; border:1px solid black; height: 300px; float:left; margin-top: 2px; margin-left: 2px; }
#BR { width:50%; border:1px solid black; height: 300px; float:right; margin-top: 2px; margin-left: 2px; }
```

**Here is output from current code:**

[image]

Comment: Add `* {box-sizing: border-box}` in your css and search about this property.

Comment: Both margins and border widths are not accounted for when computing the 50% width. You will have to use `box-sizing: border-box` to force the width to include border width, and use `calc()` to account for the additional horizontal margins. So you will have to use `width: calc(50% - 2px);`.

Comment: you are telling each div to be 50% (so a total of 100%) but then giving each a margin meaning they take up more than 100%. hence why the second goes down to the next line

Answer (score 1):

You should decrease the width of #BL and #BR elements or remove margin-left. Your siblings take more than 100% of parent width. 100%+margins.

Comment: I tried by decreasing size by even giving size in px to about half, but again the right one appears at bottom right with say 25% space of the div using.

Comment: #controls { height: 600px; width: 800px }
#wrapper { width: 800px;  height: 300px }
#TM { width:100%; border:1px solid black; height: 300px }
#BL { width:49%; border:1px solid black; height: 300px; float:left; margin-top: 2px;  }
#BR { width:49%; border:1px solid black; height: 300px; float:right; margin-top: 2px; margin-left: 2px; }

Comment: I kind of used same size earlier, even used exact px and also 25%, but BR div goes down in this case too consuming 25% of the so called wrapper div.

Comment: Strange, I haven't had any problems. Did you try to copy my CSS and apply it without any changes?

Answer (score 1):

Use `box-sizing: border-box`

```css
*{box-sizing: border-box}
#controls {
  height: 600px;
  width: 800px
}
#wrapper {
  width: 800px;
  height: 300px
}
#TM {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px
}
#BL {
  width: calc(50% - 2px);
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  float: left;
  margin-top: 2px;

}
#BR {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  height: 300px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 2px;

}
```

```html
<section id="controls" class="body">
  <div id="TM" class="body">
    <img src="images/maps.PNG" height="100%" width="100%" alt="location" class="photo" />
  </div>
  <div id="wrapper" class="body">
    <div id="BL" class="body"></div>
    <div id="BR" class="body"></div>
  </div>
</section>
<!-- /#controls -->
<section id="extras" class="body">
  <div class="blogroll">
  </div>
  <!-- /.blogroll -->
  <div class="social">
  </div>
  <!-- /.social -->
</section>
<!-- /#controls -->
```

Comment: thank you Abhishek: I tried this but other than it removed bit of overlapping of the bottom two divs, it resulted same.

Comment: You are using margins as well, so you need to remove margin or you can reduce div size depends on margin, I gave `width: calc(50% - 2px);` to `#BL`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is `Float` in css.
if you want to place two divs side by side you should style both of them same float.

> `#left_one{float:left}`
>   `#right_one{float:left}`

```
#BL { width:50%; border:1px solid black; height: 300px; float:left; margin-top: 2px; margin-left: 2px; }
#BR { width:50%; border:1px solid black; height: 300px; float:left; margin-top: 2px; margin-left: 2px; }
```

Comment: I tried this too earlier, though in this case BR goes under BL consuming 50% of space underneath

Answer (score 0):

To fit 2 DIVs side by side, Either they should be inlined block or floated blocks. In addition of that;

Container width = OuterWidth of Div1 + OuterWidth of Div2

OuterWidth of Div = margin-left + DIV's width + margin-right + 2 x border width

Since you have 1px border and 2px margin one side. You need to subtract them from the width of div.

Comment: You can also use outline property instead of border if applicable.

Comment: Bordered box is also one of the approach to deal this. Here is a good [link](https://designshack.net/articles/css/beating-borders-the-bane-of-responsive-layout/)